# Is there a good estimate for $\sum_n\frac{1}{\cos(n\theta)}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, reference-request, trigonometric-series

> Is there a good estimate for the following series (when $\theta$ is very small)?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor\frac{\pi}{4\theta}\rfloor}\frac{1}{\cos(n\theta)}$$

My original problem is:

> Given a right trangle $OAB$ where A is the right angle; additionally we assume that $OA=AB$. Now we divide AB into $m$ equal parts by $m+1$ points (including $A$ and $B$.) Then connect $O$ with each of these $m+1$ points. Estimate the sum of these $m+1$ segments.

I know my problem is **not** the same as the series above, so any idea to estimate the series or to attack my original problem is welcome.

Exact or rigorous solutions are **unnecessary** for me because this is actually an engineering problem. Some approach which "kinda makes sense" is good enough for me.

Comment: If $S$ is the sum, then a crude estimate is $$m\times OA \le S\le \sqrt 2 m \times OA$$

Comment: You should ask the "original" question as a separate post, since you acknowledge that it isn't the same as the series. (If you think it's important to do so, you can always provide links from one question to another.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The following addresses the original question that was asked by the OP.

---

One could approximate the sum of the diagonal segments by using Riemann sums.

The sum of the lengths of the diagonal segments, $S(m)$, is given by

$$S(m)=m\times OA\left(\frac1m \sum_{n=1}^m \sqrt{1+(n/m)^2}\right)$$

The parenthetical term is the Riemann sum for

$$\begin{align}\int_0^1\sqrt{1+x^2}\,dx &=\frac12(\sqrt 2 +\text{sinh}^{-1}(1))\\\\
&\approx 1.1478
\end{align}$$

So, for large $m$, the sum can be approimated by

$$\begin{align}
S(m)&\approx \frac12(\sqrt 2+\text{sinh}^{-1}(1)) \,(m\times OA)\\\\
& \approx 1.1478\,( m\times OA)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Would the anonymous down voter care to comment?

Comment: if they do, call the _New York Times_. It's so unusual it must be a headline grabbing event.

Comment: @oscarlanzi Now that was funny.

Comment: @HLC This solution should provide you with an approximation for the sum when $\theta$ is small, which means that the number of segments, $m$, in the "original" problem is large.